# Unidentified Variable using array_combine with extract using $_SESSION stored on array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have an 2 array:

```
 $arr1 = array($_SESSION['a'], $_SESSION['b']);
 $arr2 = array("1", "2");
```

I used this code to work for:

```
 extract(array_combine($arr1, $arr2));
```

Output will be:

```
 $_SESSION['a'] = 1;
 $_SESSION['b'] = 2;
```

When I gonna store it to another array which is the value of the output:

```
 $_SESSION['abcd'] = array($_SESSION['a'], $_SESSION['b']);
```

When I run it the output tells me that

```
 Unidentified a
 Unidentified b
```

Comment: Pleae do a `var_dump($_SESSION);` upfront. Everything else would be much speculation.

Comment: Can you post more of your code, its unclear as to how you're actually getting to the undefined issue.

Comment: `$_SESSION['a']` and `b` are arrays?

Comment: @StevenFarley thats the whole code. When I run it says Notice: Undefined index: a & Notice: Undefined index: b

Comment: @hakre i still got errors using var_dump

Comment: @myel: Sure. `var_dump` outputs the data, see http://php.net/var_dump`. To prevent the error, too, do: `var_dump($_SESSION); die();`. Then do a view-source in your browswer and paste the output from the `var_dump` into the top of your question. Mark it as code so it's readable.

Comment: @hakre it says Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION

Comment: It should work... See http://codepad.org/RquJOiKS

Comment: @Qoop nope the $_SESSION[a] = 1; and $_SESSION[b] = 2; is the output not assigned variable.

Comment: Good point, I'm a moron.

Comment: @Qoop nope youre not maybe my explanation is too bad.

Comment: @myel: Do not use undefined variables. Just don't use them. Take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) on this, this requires that `$_SESSION['a']` and `$_SESSION['b']` have values. Also you need to have a session before accessing the `$_SESSION`;

```
$arr1 = array($_SESSION['a'], $_SESSION['b']);
$arr2 = array("1", "2");
```

Let's say you have:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['a'] = 'keya';
$_SESSION['b'] = 'keyb';
$arr1 = array($_SESSION['a'], $_SESSION['b']);
$arr2 = array("1", "2");
extract(array_combine($arr1, $arr2));
// array_combine will return
// Array
// (
//     [keya] => 1
//     [keyb] => 2
// )
// then running extract on this array will produce
echo $keya; // "1"
echo $keyb; // "2"
```

So when you store in another session variable, it should look like this

```
$_SESSION['abcd'] = array($keya, $keyb);
```

Comment: how come the $_SESSION must have a value store? extract(array_combine($arr1, $arr2)); will output the value of $_SESSION['a'] = 1; $_SESSION['b'] = 2; but when I stored it on $_SESSION['abcd'] it says Unidentified a and b.

Answer (score 0):

The value is getting assigned.I didnt face any problem.try this

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['a']=a;
$_SESSION['b']=b;'
$arr1 = array($_SESSION['a'], $_SESSION['b']); 
$arr2 = array(1,2);
extract(array_combine($arr1, $arr2));
echo $_SESSION['a']."<br/>";
echo $_SESSION['b']."<br/>";
$_SESSION['abcd'] = array($_SESSION['a'], $_SESSION['b']);
echo $_SESSION['abcd'][0]."<br/>";
echo $_SESSION['abcd'][1]."<br/>";
```

Comment: I just edited your answer, see the formatting?

Comment: you made it wrong cause you assigned $_SESSION['a'] & $_SESSION['b']

Comment: my expectation is                                                  $arr1 = array($_SESSION['a'], $_SESSION['b']);
$arr2 = array("1", "2"); using extract and array_combine it gonna be $arr1 will be a variable and $arr2 gonna be the value of the variable $arr1 which is working when I assign it to $_SESSION['abcd'] = array($_SESSION['a'], $_SESSION['b']); it says Unidentified variables of a and b.

Comment: see it keeps getting me an error :(

Answer (score 0):

Now I get it (I'm gutted it took me so long).

`array combine` works how @ace says.

It is getting the names of the variables from the values of arr1 (so '' and '' as they aren't being set anywhere, ie `$_SESSION['a'] = '' && $_SESSION['b'] = ''`) and then the values from arr2 (so '1' and '1') meaning your combined array would be `array('' => 2)` (due to being overwritten).

`values of array1 supplies keys`

`values of array2 supplies values`

This then means that the variable being extracted is technically $ (as in an name of '' but, obviously, this isn't a valid variable).

If you had set `$_SESSION['a'] = 'aaa'; $_SESSION['b'] = 'bbb';` and then used `$_SESSION['abcd'] = array($aaa, $bbb);` instead of `$_SESSION['abcd'] = array($_SESSION['a'], $_SESSION['b']);` then it kind of works.

http://codepad.org/xH9tEwxR

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `session_start()` at the top. You can't work with `$_SESSION` until then.

Answer (score 0):

```
array($_SESSION['a'], $_SESSION['b'])
```

This makes a new array with **the values** of whatever `$_SESSION['a']` and `$_SESSION['b']` are at this time. Let's assume they're not set and hence `null`. The result is `array(null, null)`.

Variables are placeholders for **values**. The **values** are used here, not the variables themselves.

> ```
> extract(array_combine($arr1, $arr2));
> ```
>
> Output will be:
>
> ```
> $_SESSION['a'] = 1;
> $_SESSION['b'] = 2;
> ```

This assumption is simply patently wrong, hence your other assumptions that rest on it aren't working either.